# Script suddenly not working at Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity I added simple button...and I have simple following code

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button mk;

    void Start () 
    {
        mk.onClick.AddListener(asd);
    }

    void asd()
    {
        print(" asd");
    }
}
```

I added this script into canvas...this was working fine..but after restarting suddenly it is not working at all...I also tried add another script and this not working.. I think something wrong happened to this canvas.Antoher canvas works fine.

Comment: Did you check if your `mk` is actually assigned through inspector or any other script?

Comment: yes it is. @m.rogalski I added it into the inspector

Answer (score 0):

It can be because, you doesn't have EventSystem in your scene. Even if you have it, try to delete and add it again. It solved my problem once.

[EventSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventSystem.html)